# How to edit <head> codes of an individual page/post?

Tags: custom-header

I want to run a **JavaScript** and I want to paste in inside the  `<head></head>` tag

I do not want to add it to the text-view area.

How can I add this code snippet to an individual post (I mean not editing the headers.php)?

Comment: Google about these terms `wp_head`, `is_page()`, `is_single()`!

Answer (score 5):

You want to hook into the Header code using something like this:

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript');

function hook_javascript() {
    if (is_single('123')) { 
        $output="<script> enter your script here </script>";
        echo $output;
    }
}
```

More information available here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Comment: As @cybmeta pointed out on another answer, it would probably be better using wp_enqueue_scripts if you're using a javascript file rather than a few lines of code.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but just to add to it in case the original poster isn't aware, the place to put this code is in your theme's `functions.php`